# CruiseControl SVN Exception

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I get the following error sometimes(mostly overnight) when svn is trying to connect to the repository to check for updates:

ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'RepositoryURL': could not connect to server (ServerName)

I have to manually force build the project in order to have the successful build again. 
How can I avoid this or have cruiscontrol build the project again(automatically) when this happens

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution you may consider is to setup a filter trigger to not run builds during the evening.

[Filter Trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filter+Trigger)